# How to compare two ISO standard fingerprint templates?

Tags: comparison, fingerprint, iso-19794

I have found the *Digital persona Finger FX* Open source project that allows me to supply finger print images (bitmap) and saves the fingerprint minutiae data in *ISO/IEC 19794-2:2005* format.

https://github.com/FingerJetFXOSE/FingerJetFXOSE.git

How to compare two such ISO/IEC 19794-2:2005 templates?

Can anyone suggest any sample source code or article?

Answer (score 2):

[SourceAFIS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourceafis/) has a partial implementation of ISO/IEC 19794-2 and comes with some examples in .NET and Java (experimental).

Answer (score 1):

Code for comparing the ISO templates is not openly available. You need to go through [ISO/IEC 19794-2](http://camsunit.com/application/javascript-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html#compare-fingerprint)  documentation and implement your own. We tried but ended up with wrong results (like accepting wrong fingerprints, rejecting valid fingerprints). There are fingerprint matching services available which you can try if you are open for the 3rd party services

1. [CAMS](http://camsunit.com/application/javascript-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html#compare-fingerprint)
2. [M2Sys](http://www.m2sys.com)
3. [Neurotechnology](https://www.neurotechnology)